# How does JPA gets auto-generated ID of persisted object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I've been playing around with JDBC and Spring JPA and what made me think is how Spring gets ID of saved object.
I've extended JpaRepository:

```
interface UserAccountRepository
    extends JpaRepository<UserAccount, Integer> {
}
```

and saved my object:

```
userAccountRepository.save(new UserAccount(
        null,
        username,
        passwordEncoder.encode(password)
));
```

MySQL log shows these operations:

> 2017-04-08T12:54:52.107156Z      78 Query SET autocommit=0
>
> 2017-04-08T12:54:52.206061Z      78 Query insert into user_account (password, username) values ('encryptedpassword', 'user')
>
> 2017-04-08T12:54:52.206823Z      78 Query commit
>
> 2017-04-08T12:54:52.211045Z      78 Query SET autocommit=1

Since insert operation does not return anything (or am i missing something?) how is it possible that Spring knows that id without any additional queries?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys--

Comment: Spring doesnt get anything. Spring doesnt do JPA. A JPA provider does JPA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDBC can return the keys that were generated as part of the statement.  Here is an example:

```
  try(PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
    setParameters(parameterValues, statement);

    statement.execute();

    try(ResultSet rs = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
      if(rs.next()) {
        return rs.getObject(1);  // <-- contains the generated key
      }

      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/0a2a5c622e3eb30724e80bc8661c0ac55ebfb2be/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/identity/MySQLIdentityColumnSupport.java) of Hibernate ORM (which I guess it's the one you're using with Spring), looks like it performs this query to know the last inserted id:

`select last_insert_id()`